# Adding rows according to set number in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

how to adjust the code below, so that it applies only to the active cell and not to all the cells in the column A. Otherwise, the code works fine.
Thanks!

```
Public Sub Insert()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual   'pre XL97 xlManual

lastrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, 1).Select

Set CurrentCell = ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow, 1)

For n = lastrow To 0 Step -1
    If n = lastrow Then GoTo CheckLastRow
    If n = 1 Then GoTo CheckfirstRow
        ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 0).Select

CheckLastRow:
    Set NextCell = CurrentCell.Offset(-1, 0)

        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        For i = 1 To CurrentCell
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
        Next i

    Set CurrentCell = NextCell
Next n

'To be performed on the firstrow in the column
CheckfirstRow:
        ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
        For i = 1 To CurrentCell
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
        Next i
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? From what I see, you are inserting 2 empty rows below the first and above the last?

Comment: If I put f.e. number of 50 into A4,then 50 rows are inserted, exactly what I need. The problem is, if I do it for A5  (with number 43) then 43 rows are inserted under A5 but AT THE SAME time under A4 are AGAIN 50 rows inserted but I only wanted to add 43 under A5.

Comment: So you put 10 in "A5", Select "A5", execute the Macro and 10 rows are inserted below row 5?

Comment: Yes, thats what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want to accomplish is what you describe in your comment, this code should work for you:

```
Public Sub Insert()

r = ActiveCell.Value
Set myRange = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow

For i = 1 To r
    myRange.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Lean solution, just the Debug.Print is optional and spams the console

Comment: You take the code as it is and replace your code with it. Then you as before select a cell e.g. "A5" and execute the routine

Comment: "Can t execute code in break mode" This is what I get. The set data in spreadsheet: everywhere I have some text values and in A5 I have 43

Comment: Then you have some code around the Sub that is not embedded in a Sub (e.g. a Set... somewhere floating around)